# How to connect to your device from terminal using adb commands

Tags: android, terminal, adb, android-studio-plugin

While searching for

> debug Android applications over Wi-Fi

I came across the plugin - '**Android WiFi ADB**' available in Android studio.

When I tried to install the plugin, Android Studio suggested '**WiFi ADB
Ultimate**'.

Or is it better to connect with terminal? If Yes, how?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I felt connecting your device with terminal using **adb commands** is more helpful than these plugins.

Steps:

1. You need to connect your device to your computer via USB cable. Make sure USB debugging is working. You can check if it shows up when running **adb devices**

[image]

2. Run **adb tcpip 5555**

[image]

3. Disconnect your device (remove the USB cable).
4. Go to the Settings -> About phone -> Status to view the IP address of your phone.
5. Run **adb connect < IP address of your device > :5555**

[image]

6. If you run adb devices again, you should see your device.

[image]

Now you can execute adb commands or use your favorite IDE for android development - wireless!

Credits / Reference: 
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-debug-your-android-app-over-wifi-without-root

Comment: This was life saver. For some weird reason I could not use WiFi ADB so I had to do some manual setup. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Try **WIFI ADB ULTIMATE**.

It worked the first time for me.

**Instructions:**

1. Find and install the plugin in Android Studio settings
2. Restart Android Studio
3. Plug in your phone using a USB cable
4. Select View->Tools Window->WIFI ADB ULTIMATE
5. You should now see your device listed (press the refresh icon, if needed).

Once the remote device is listed you can unplug your USB cable.

Answer (score 1):

**WIFI ADB ULTIMATE** worked for me.

add the plugin.

- The plugin gets added to the left side of android studio.
- Click the plugin
- Refresh the device list
- It will show the USB connected android devices
- Make sure that the device, you want to connect with the system containing android studio over WIFI share the same WIFI network.
- Now click the play button.
- If every thing were in write place , you android device would have been connected with system adb over WIFI.
- Now you may disconnect the android device from the USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

Try ADB WIFI connect it is best

Answer (score 0):

Wifi Adb Ultimate is cool
but you have to be careful about 1 thing.
After disconnecting wifi you have 24 hours to connect again through same wifi otherwise it will reset, not the IP but the connection.