# Why WIFIADB not working in with android studio at all?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

While I am trying to run wifiadb or any sort of plugin the application hangs while showing this

```
04-26/10:14 CmdUtils.execSync:48: adb version
04-26/10:14 CmdUtils$resolve$1.accept:76: >Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
04-26/10:14 CmdUtils$resolve$1.accept:76: >Version 28.0.2-debian
04-26/10:14 CmdUtils$resolve$1.accept:76: >Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
04-26/10:14 Config.loadDevices:50: []
04-26/10:14 CmdUtils.execSync:48: adb devices -l
04-26/10:14 CmdUtils$resolve$1.accept:76: >List of devices attached
04-26/10:14 CmdUtils$resolve$1.accept:76: >
04-26/10:14 Config.saveDevice:57: []
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Is adb via USB working? First time you need to run the ADB over USB before you can run it over WIFI.

Comment: It is working. But somehow I can't work it out. I want to do do it over wifi after connecting with USB. USB working fine but Wifi not.

Comment: Did you `adb connect <ip>:<port, default 5555>`?

Comment: @GenoChen thanks for the reply. Looks like I forgot to trigger some commands before the command you mentioned. It is working now. Now I can work without WIFI ADB Plugins.

Comment: @GenoChen this is the solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992965/how-to-connect-device-to-android-studio-wifi-adb-ultimate-or-android-wifi-adb-o

Answer (score 0):

You may forgot to `adb connect <ip>:<port, default 5555>`.

`adb` will never know which device (ip) you want to connect before you tell him with a `adb connect`.

Answer (score 0):

The whole process it (assuming you are using android studio)
Connect the device with PC. Before that you should activate Developer mode and check USB Debugger.
Then run command:
`adb tcpip 5555`

After this try to connect with
adb connect : The default port is 5555

If this is not working then activate adb while charge mode. This worked for me.