# Problem with Android wireless debugging - "unexpected error during Wi-Fi pairing initialization" - no other info

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am having trouble enabling wireless debugging in Android Studio.  In fact when I select "Pair Devices using Wi-Fi", I get an almost instant error with the very general (useless) message "unexpected error during Wi-Fi pairing initialization".  I was very surprised being that **I was unable to find any posts or pages when googling for that specific message**!

Android Studio provides a "learn more" link that opens up [this page](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless-adb-android-11) and is basically useless—it describes basic steps which I will copy below. I can't find any logs or more specific error messages. I tried rebooting the PC, restarting Android Studio, turning off any firewalls/anti virus, trying with phone plugged in (USB debugging works fine, I can load apps to the phone when plugged in no problem), ADB restart, updated Android Studio and SDK platform tools. Nothing changes; it is the same message (see the screenshot at the bottom).

What bugs me is that because the error message pops up almost instantly, **the whole "service" seems to be unable** to start completely.  I have researched extensively, but most errors are quite specific and deal with network/IP issues or pairing problems, etc.—but all those are *after* some initial steps do take place.

I am running [Android Studio 15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio#Version_history) (Dolphin) | 2021.3.1.

I have a Samsung s21FE running [Android 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_12) (although I don't think that is even relevant, it never starts looking for devices anyway).

I have followed all steps in relevant guides, for example [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless-adb-android-11), namely:

1. Ensure that your workstation and device are connected to the same wireless network.
2. Ensure that your device is running [Android 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_11) or higher. For more information, see Check & update your Android version.
3. Ensure that you have [Android Studio Bumblebee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio#Version_history) (2021.1.1). You can download it here.
4. On your workstation, update to the latest version of the SDK Platform-Tools.

The error I see is this:

[image]

---

I solved it by following a suggestion from the comments submitted on this post. See below.

Comment: Have you tried pairing your device using adb from terminal using "adb pair your_ip:your_port" ?

Comment: directly on wifi you mean, or while usb connected?

Comment: While connected on wifi

Comment: i will try and report what happened. thanks.

Comment: I did connect wirelessly with adb connect 192.168.1.6:5555. Followed advice from here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992965/how-to-connect-to-your-device-from-terminal-using-adb-commands 
And I see: List of devices attached - 192.168.1.6:5555        device
However nothing changes within android studio.

Comment: If you re connected with your device now you should be able to use it to run the app

Comment: Yep, it worked! Thanks!!! I now see two devices (one with the ip) and indeed when I disconnect the USB able, one device remains connected (through wifi I guess) and app does install wirelessly. Thanks a lot buddy .. I guess an AS bug through its UI ?

Comment: I never used the ui to connect/pair inside android studio so I can't tell if it's a bug, glad to be helpful

Comment: I had the same issue after updating to dolphin and being in a new wifi network. At first I thought it may be a bug in dolphin. Starting pc and mobile device new solved my issue.

Comment: You need to disable & re-enable adb mDNS from Android Studio, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70944858/android-studio-bumblebee-wifi-pairing-issue

Answer (score 25):

Try upgrading the SDK Platform tools in menu *Tools* → *SDK Manager* → *SDK Tools*.

[image: SDK manager]

Comment: That fixed the issue, somehow I had no `Platform-Tools` installed.

Answer (score 5):

I have fixed this problem by closing Android Studio and opening it again.

Answer (score 5):

I had to:

- Hold "Wireless Debugging" on the device to be able to see "Pair device with pairing code".
  [Wireless Debugging Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYhkN.png)
- On windows host (where Android Studio is), then use `adb pair [ip.address]:[port displayed on device]`
  [Pair Device w/ Pairing code Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaWMO.png)
- Enter code in shell shown on device
- In shell, then enter `adb connect [ip.address]:[port listed in Wireless debugging]` - This is different than the previous port used and is shown in the main section of Wireless Debugging
  [Device IP/Port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7sO3.png)
- After connection, use `adb shell` to test or go directly to Android Studio and the device is listed in "Device Manager"

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this problem by restarting the PC.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue being within a corporate VPN on Windows.

I solved it following below steps (of which some might be optinal):

1. Pair the Device and Windows Computer over Bluetooth
2. On Windows: Enter a Personal Area Network (using the small bluetooth icon in the taskbar)
3. In the following window, select the Phone, and choose "Connect via" and then "Direct connection" (i hope the translation is correct here)
4. Android: Enable Wireless debugging
5. Select "Pair device with pairing code"
6. A window pops up telling you IP-address, [paring port] & [pairing code]
7. If your IP address shows as 10.1.10.1, find your device's [real ip address] in the device's WiFi settings, otherwise, use the shown address as [real ip address]
8. Windows: Open a terminal and enter `.\adb pair [real ip address]:[pairing port]`
9. If prompted for the pairing code, enter it
10. On the device in the Wireless Debugging Settings Window, note the different [connect port] under "IP address & Port"
11. On windows in the terminal, enter `.\adb connect [real ip address]:[connect port]`
12. After a while, IDEA should now dected and show the device in device manager > physical devices